# How to remove highlight border of a navigationmenu in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, css, highlight, navigationbar

I'm using the navigationmenu in the toolbox of ASP.NET, and I'm not able to remove an annoying golden border, I also can't find anything about it. The golden border only appears when I click on a navigation Item, and when I click on somewhere else on the page the border will get removed. ( the navigationmenu works with javascript so I won't be redirected to another page ). I also looked at it with firebug and when I click on a navigationItem a css class "highlighted" is added to the item. Can someone tell me how to get rid of the golden border?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/highlight.png/

Comment: Did you try finding the border with firebug? As Gurvinder said, you can use !important but this property should be avoided when possible, because an uncommented declaration in a style sheet has a negative impact in maintainability, among other reasons... do you have an online example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `!important` property in CSS class for avoiding border.